# Am I calculating my drone's power consumption right?

Tags: motor, battery, brushless-motor, power, amperage

I want to make an drone with these motors: [https://www.amazon.com/XtremeAmazing-2200KV-Brushless-2212-6-helicopter/dp/B01M3UBGU9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M3UBGU9)

1: First of all, are they good? If not, could you suggest me other motors?

2: If they need 12V and their max power is 342W, is the max current is 28,5A?

3: If the max current is 28,5A/motor x 4 motors x 65% power = 74,1A?

4: If the motors take 74,1A and I have a 3000mAh battery, does this mean I can only use my drone for 2,43 minutes?

(3000mAh / 74 100mA = 0,04...h = 2,429min)

5: If yes, 2,43min is not a lot, how should I do to be able to use my drone for at least 15min without having to recharge the battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations assume that the motor will be running at full power all the time.

Assuming your quadcopter's weight is less than 4 times the max motor thrust (which it needs to be to have any control), then you won't be running at full power.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at this

https://www.ecalc.ch/xcoptercalc_mobile.php

or this kind of websites.

I cannot comment on answers, but wanted to share this.